# Datasheet for this ic

Tags: power-supply, power-electronics, identification

I had an old mobile charger laying around and I planned to build an SMPS out of it. But on looking I found that it contained an ic with parts no sg68502sz. When I searched online for this IC I couldn't find the datasheet. So I settled for the next best thing: an IC with similar numbering, and found sg6848. However, not only but this every IC manufactured by the manufacturer has the same pinouts and rating, but after learning the datasheet and reverse engineering the PCB I was amazed that this IC doesn't correspond to any of them.

I know that it is a soic8 PWM IC but it doesn't have secondary feedback and I guessed that it is a primary regulator switching IC.
Can this IC be identified, and its datasheet found?

[image]

The connections I found are:

1-about 2M resistor to 300 V

2- ground

3-100k and a capacitor in parallel to gnd

4-39k and a capacitor in parallel to gnd

5-about 29k and cap in parallel to gnd

6-ground

7-various connections to auxiliary winding

8- 100ohm res to base of transistor and this is the output pin.

Though I know some of the pins it is not enough.

Comment: What do you mean it's sop6? that's clearly soic-8.

Comment: Sorry I meant to say sop8

Comment: Soic8 I meant to say

Comment: google finds this ... https://www.jotrin.com/product/parts/SG68502SZ

Comment: @jsotola Yeah but it needs an account. Can you give other links ?even a datasheet of similar or replacement ic would do.